# How to understand java regular expression backslash

Tags: java, regex

I think I get confused about Java's regular expression backslash. Sometimes we need double backslash. However,sometimes we need just one. For example why `\.`(what does this mean?) can not match a normal dot, it needs `\\.` However, the `\t` can match the tab. If someone put arbitrary number of backslash, how to interpret the meaning. For example if I write `\\\\t`, what does it mean.

Comment: Also see [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: In short, it's because the \ character is already predefined for Java Strings. Also see: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Backslash is a escape character in Java and Regular Expression.

Comment: \\\\t gets to \\t and this matches a backslash followed by t